# Promise pattern for nested readFiles in node

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm new to node and promises and I'm getting confused.

I'm reading a json which has information about what other json files I need to read. It looks like this:

```
{ 
    id: 1,
    name: "My name",
    includes: [
        "#include1.json",
        "#include2.json",
        "#include3.json"
    ]
}
```

an include file looks like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Include 1",
    details: "I am include 1"
}
```

What I need to do is read the master json and then construct a complete json document with all the given includes, so it will look like this:

```
{ 
    id: 1,
    name: "My name",
    includes: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Include 1",
            details: "I am include 1"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Include 2",
            details: "I am include 2"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Include 3",
            details: "I am include 3"
        },
    ]
}
```

The master json file will dictate what includes are included.

I put the readFile method into a function that returns a promise

```
function readFile(filename, enc, err){
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    if(err) reject(err);
     fs.readFile(filename, enc, function (err, res){
      if (err) reject(err);
      else fulfill(res);
    });
  });
}
```

and my service file consumes that

```
serviceReturnJsonPromise = function() {
 return readFile(masterPath, 'utf8', err).then(function (masterData){
  return JSON.parse(masterData);
 });
}
```

which returns the master json OK

but now Im stuck with the includes

```
serviceReturnJsonPromise = function() {
 return readFile(masterPath, 'utf8', err).then(function (masterData){
  var master = JSON.parse(masterData);
  var includes = [];

  _.each(master.includes, function(include) {

    var includePath = "./" + item.replace("#","");

    return readFile(includePath, 'utf8', err).then(function (includeData){
      includes.push(JSON.parse(includeData));
    });
  });
 });
}
```

You can see its not finished yet but this bit doesnt work because the promises arent stacked. I know how I would stack the promises using all but I dont know what the includes will be until ive read the master.

If you all can give me any good starting point for learning about node and promises I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Look into `Promise.all`

Comment: Do never use `forEach` (or `_.each`). Use `map`, then you won't even have to use `push`. Use `Promise.all` after collecting the individual promises (for the results of each file) in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mistaken when you tried to read includes and do not wait for the results. The promise gets resolved with zero data before the first include file is read.

This should work:

```
serviceReturnJsonPromise = function () {
    return readFile(masterPath, 'utf8', err)
        .then(function (masterData) {
            var master = JSON.parse(masterData);

            // map over includes array and return "read" promises
            var includes = master.includes.map(function (item) {
                var includePath = "./" + item.replace("#", "");

                return readFile(includePath, 'utf8', err).then(function (includeData) {
                    return JSON.parse(includeData)
                });
            });

            // wait for all file reads
            return Promise.all(includes).then(jsons=>{
                master.includes = jsons;
                return master;
            })
        });
}
```

There is a nice [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2d7s3spWAzo) with promises explained.

P.S. Check out the channel too, there's a lot well-explained js topics.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this solved it. The video was a great resource too, kudos.

Answer (score 0):

@EricP Since you just want to work with json imports you can directly `require` them without using the `fs` module. It'll go something like this -

```
const path = require('path')
const main = require(path.resolve('main.json'))

const readFile = (children) => {
  const result = children.map((file) => {
    const child = require(path.resolve(file))
    if(child.includes){
      child.includes = readFile(child.includes)
    } 
    return child
  })
  children.includes = result
  return result;
}

console.dir(readFile(main.includes), {depth: null})
```

#### Explanation

The readFile utility ( can be named better ), recursively resolves down the includes tree and set the result back.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A running repl can be found here - https://repl.it/repls/HummingBlueClasses

Comment: It's impossible to re-read files this way, at least without cache mangling. It's unknown what's the context for this code and whether this is a problem. but this should be taken into consideration.